# How to get the invitation for Provisioning API??

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How to get the invitation for  Provisioning API??

Per this article its only available by inviation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/

Answer (score -1):

What part of

> Caution: The Provisioning API is currently available by invitation
>   only.

do you not understand?

Comment: What part of "How to get the invitation for Provisioning API?" do you not understand?